# Can we develop a "should slug"?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few too many questions that begin "Should X do Y"?

To my mind those are intrinsically subjective questions and a bad fit for StackExchange. Should is always evaluated against some external, situational criteria.

I know that the FAQ currently includes

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

Let me reify this into subordinate questions:

1. Am I overreacting? is this just me?  Are there fewer question than I think?
2. Is "should...." automatically a subjective question? Am I dead wrong?
3. Do we think the FAQ effectively addresses the problem?
4. What is the best way to discourage "Should..." questions while encouraging the querent?

Comment: If possible Mark, can you provide examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes certain keywords can indicate that a question might not be constructive. I generally edit these out first if I'm in doubt as to whether or not the question is really too subjective.

If the edits show that the question isn't too subjective/not constructive, then I move on. However, editing, including fixing spelling and grammar, can sometimes remove any constraints that make it hard to evaluate the question on its own merits.

In general, our community tends to lean towards accepting subjective questions, and as long as they're about real problems, they tend to work out really well on our site. Check out [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for some more examples of the difference between a good subjective question and a bad one.

With that said, if you provide specific examples, we're happy to discuss and review them, as questions of quality are important. :)